# Find folder of specific file

Tags: regex, unix, sed, find

I am trying to find the folder location of a specific file, for this example `libgfortran.so`.

What I've tried so far is:

```
find 2>/dev/null / -name libgfortran.so
```

... which will output something like the following to `stdout` (redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.so
```

From this I want to extract just the folder (without a trailing `/`):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
```

I've got as far as trying something like:

```
find 2>/dev/null / -name libgfortran.so | sed 's/\(\/.*\/\)/\1/'
```

... which I was hoping would capture what is between the first and last `/` (I would then need to remove the last `/`), but the output I get is still:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.so
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: @Androbin this gives `sed: -e expression #1, char 12: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: Sorry, I meant sed 's|\(.*\)/|\1|g'

Comment: @Androbin exactly the same error results from that one too

Comment: I'm afraid, SO stripped my backslashes.

Comment: Put them before the opening and closing brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -name libgfortran.so -exec dirname {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks.  Out of interest, any real difference between your answer and that of @JeanBaptiste?

Comment: This one will take more than one argument in account.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
dirname `find 2>/dev/null / -name libgfortran.so`
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `sed`:

```
find 2>/dev/null / -name libgfortran.so | sed -E 's#(/.*)/(.*)#\1#g'
```

where `-E` tells sed to use a regular expression, so you don't have to escape the paratheses. The group `\1` is your path and `\2` would be the filename.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in a simpler fashion using grep:

```
find 2>/dev/null / -name libgfortran.so | grep -o '\/.*\/'
```

Comment: Close, but this leaves a trailing `/` :)

Comment: ah, sorry, I thought that would not be relevant. Then, see my second solution (which I just edited), or the solution of @user3100381, which is the nicer one in fact